# How to show always the top bar when editing

Tags: wp-admin, user-interface

While viewing a page, or editing a theme, the topbar disappears and I can't find a way to make it always visible.

Is there a way to always show it?
[image]

Comment: If your profile settings have the admin toolbar showing on the frontend, then your theme may be hiding the bar using CSS. You'll need to investigate the CSS rules applied to the admin toolbar, and remove.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what I mean is that when I am in other parts of the interface, like editing a post, or editing the theme, the top bar dissapears, and I didn't find a way to make it always visible independently from the place I am.

Comment: Could it be possible that you are editing in full screen mode? Gutenberg automatically sets you to full screen mode, which removes the top bar and the sidebar. You can change it in the settings while editing a post or page.